# fix access denied for root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in init.php on line 2

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, e-commerce, linux-mint, lampp

I have an e-commerce website, and I m trying to move from localhost windows to Linux Mint. the problem is that I can't connect to database.

I see my config.inc.php in lampp/phpmy admin and the username is root and password = ""

I don't know how to fix this.

```
    <?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'ecommerce');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Database connection failed with following errors: '.mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ecommerce/config.php';
    require_once BASEURL.'helpers/helpers.php';
```

Comment: Has the database server changed? It sounds like your windows environ may have had a db server with a blank password, but now on your mint box the db may require different credentials.

Comment: no i didnt change the database , i exported and imported to my new localhost